# Issue with infowindows remaining active when another KML layer is selected - Google Maps API V3

Tags: google-maps-api-3, kml, infowindow

I've got multiple kml layers that are loaded into my Google Map API V3 using tick boxes. When two or more layers are selected the infowindows on one layer don't automatically collapse when markers are clicked on other layers. I'd like the infowindows to close automatically even though they are on different KML layers - Any pointers in the right direction will be helpful.

Thanks

Darren Wilson

Comment: But you can have more than one InfoWindow open at once. What makes you think the observed behaviour is wrong? Or are you saying that it's not wrong but how do you get round it?

Comment: Hi Andrew, I only want one infowindow open at a time even if activated via different layers.

Comment: @DarrenWilson Are the InfoWindows opened by your code or are you talking InfoWindows that are provided directly by the KmlLayer?

Comment: Hi Sean, Direct from the KML layer!

Answer (score 4):

You need to disable the default info window creation and handle the infowindow yourself in code. Here's an example:

```
var CommonInfoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({"maxWidth": 500});

/** @param {...*} KmlMouseEvent */
function KmlLayerClicked(KmlMouseEvent) {
  var ClickData = /** @type {google.maps.KmlMouseEvent} */(KmlMouseEvent);

  CommonInfoWindow.close();

  if (ClickData.featureData && ClickData.featureData.id) {
    CommonInfoWindow.setOptions({ "position": ClickData.latLng,
        "pixelOffset": ClickData.pixelOffset,
        "content": ClickData.featureData.infoWindowHtml
    });
    CommonInfoWindow.open(map);
  }
}

/** @type {google.maps.KmlLayer} */
var KmlOverlay = new google.maps.KmlLayer(KmlUrl, {
    'preserveViewport': true,
    'suppressInfoWindows': true
});
google.maps.event.addListener(KmlOverlay, "click", KmlLayerClicked);
```

Comment: Hi Chad, thanks for this - I gave it a try, but it still didn't work. The InfoWindows are provided by the KML layer. Really appreciate the code! Thanks.

Comment: You missed adding this option then: `'suppressInfoWindows': true`. For this to work, you have to tell the api not to generate its own infoWindows.

Comment: Is the proposed edit your own? It is anonymous at the moment.

Comment: I'm ok with the edit (although I didn't make it). There are many variations on that code and the specifics depend on the KML file being loaded.